# Merge Sort Algorithm last step

Tags: algorithm, sorting, merge

```
// Sorts the sequence (A[p],...,A[r-1])
template<class T> 
void merge_sort(array<T>& A,int p,int r) 
{ 
  if (p<r-1)     
  { 
     int q=?; // see discussion in the text
     merge_sort(A,p,q);
     merge_sort(A,q,r);
     merge(A,p,q,r);
  }
}
```

Let's say array is [4, 9, 13, 1, 5]. **I understand the recursion,** the first merge_sort method splits the array up until the **point of [4]**, so the first and second merge sort method gets skipped.**How does it know where the rest of the array is to merge it?** Array A is now only [4], so if we call merge (A,p,q,r) it only gets the 4 and no other part of it to merge it with?

Comment: What do you mean by "up until the point of [4]`? Typically merge_sorts splits the array in two halves and sorts the lower and upper half recursively until it reaches arrays of length 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Array A is now only [4] ...  it only gets the 4 and no other part of it to merge it with.

That's were the confusion is. The array *doesn't get shorter*! At all times the array is the complete array with all its original values.

The notion of a subarray is only reflected by the additional parameters, `p` and `r`. These mark the *range* of interest in that *full* array (where `p` is the first index that is *in* the range, and `r` is the first index *after* the range).

Look for instance, at this recursive call:

```
 merge_sort(A,p,q);
```

The `p` and `q` indices mark where in the array A is the partition that we want to sort. That call will only work with that part of the array.

At a certain moment, we will have `p==0`, `q==1` and `r==2` and the above call will then look at one element only, A[0].

The next recursive call is:

```
 merge_sort(A,q,r);
```

This call will also look at one element: A[1].

These two calls will just return (as obviously nothing had to be done as a subarray with just one value is always "sorted"), and then the merge can be done with this call:

```
 merge(A,p,q,r);
```

Note that this merge call gets to work with two values: A[0] and A[1]. When this call returns we know that the values at indices 0 and 1 are now guaranteed to be in sorted order.